# How to configure dmenu to launch an application with arguments?

Tags: i3-wm, spotify, hdpi

For some background, I just barely switched my wm to i3 and am customizing it. I am very new to everything, which means that I have a lot to learn. I've been trying to get Spotify to be better scaled for my 1440p monitor on my laptop so that everything won't be super tiny. I found that by using the --force-device-scale-factor=1.5 flag, it will fix the problem. Calling spotify in the terminal like this does the trick: 
`spotify --force-device-scale-factor=1.5`
I can't find a way to configure DMenu to call Spotify with that flag. There isn't a dmenu config file that I'm aware of and can't find anywhere. This might be a super basic question, but how do you configure dmenu to open Spotify with that flag when I type in Spotify?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i3 on Ubuntu by default uses the `dmenu_run` script to provide a dmenu with all executables in your PATH, so no, you cannot launch an application directly without typing out the parameters each time (see *remarks*).

**Option 1**

You can create a wrapper script for spotify. This is a script with a line that provides the command with parameters. You could create a script named "spot", that looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
spotify --force-device-scale-factor=1.5
```

Make the script executable and put it in a folder that is listed in your $PATH. Launching "spot" will launch spotify with the desired parameters.

**Option 2**

A more elegant solution would be to replace the `dmenu_run` script with the `i3-dmenu-desktop` script. `i3-dmenu-desktop` is an i3 specific script that creates a menu based on the available .desktop files on your system. It is thus mainly targeted towards graphical programs, which actually makes more sense for an application menu and looks better.

This change can be done in your i3 config file: in the hotkey definition for dmenu (<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> in a standard i3 installation on Ubuntu), replace `dmenu_run` by `i3-dmenu-desktop`.

Then the solution is easy - and also elegant: find and open the .desktop file for spotify, find the "Exec=" line and add the parameters to the command listed on that line. You can find the .desktop file for spotify with the following command:

```
find / -name '*.desktop' -exec grep -H 'spotify' {} \; 2>/dev/null
```

*Remark*

1. It is possible in dmenu to run your application with arguments. Typing the full command in dmenu and add the parameters, then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. One could think bash aliases could come tho the rescue here. However, that would not work, because the `dmenu_run` script is populated by executable files on your system, and does not include aliases/

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed answer. It was super helpful knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

hack function `static void keypress(XKeyEvent *ev)` in dmenu.c like this:

```
case XK_KP_Enter:
        //replace you command here...
        if (strcmp(sel->text, "google-chrome")==0)
        {
            puts((sel && !(ev->state & ShiftMask)) ? "google-chrome --proxy-server=\"socks://127.0.0.1:7891\"" : text);
        } else {
            //otherwise, just run the command
            puts((sel && !(ev->state & ShiftMask)) ? sel->text : text);
        }

        if (!(ev->state & ControlMask)) {
            cleanup();
            exit(0);
        }
        if (sel)
            sel->out = 1;
        break;
```

The code is around line 490